# Trying to make expo links work behind a reverse proxy

Tags: reactjs, http, react-native, expo, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to make expo development pipeline work behind a reverse proxy, my setup for reverse proxying seems to work:
curl http://packager.desk1.code.example.com yield me

> React Native packager is running.

however, when hitting manifest server, I get this:

```
{"error":"XDLError: ValidationError: \"https\" is not allowed"}
```

which is probably the reason why scanning my exp:// code doesnt work,
so what is exactly the exp:// protocol ? is this something based on HTTP ? how can I proxy it ?

Thanks